# Add epoch time with milliseconds to a epoch date/time?

Tags: php, date, epoch

I have a function in PHP which gets a mean time of epoch dates in an array

```
Intervals - Array
(
  [0] => 86340
  [1] => 86400
  [2] => 86400
  [3] => 86400
  [4] => 86400
  [5] => 172800
  [6] => 86400
)
```

I am working the mean by adding all the elements in the array and dividing by the amount of elements in the array. My issue is sometimes it will return an epoch time like - **'98734.285714286'** rather than **'98734'**

Later on I am adding this mean time to an epoch date for example -
**'1453348800 + 98734.285714286'**

But as the epoch date has a decimal place it seems to append the first 4 numbers after the decimal place to the epoch result for example - **'1453354114.2857'** and when this is converted back to a human readable date it is returning - **2903-01-22 05:28:34**

**Please note that these epoch dates are examples.**

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is sometimes it will return an epoch time like - '98734.285714286' rather than '98734'

```
$average = intval($average);
```

No explanation required :)

Answer (score 0):

They are integers, so treat them as integers.

```
$intervals = ['86340', '85340', '1453354114.2857'];
array_walk($intervals, 'intval'); // now they are all integer
```

ANd then do with it you want, like taking te avarage:

```
$avg = intval(array_sum($intervals)/count(intervals));
```

Comment: Wrong assumption. `(3 + 2+ 3) / 3` = Integer? No. They want the answer to be an integer, not the operands

Comment: Simple add another inval, like I did above... I added it.

Comment: To make sure they are all integers. OP wasn't very clear about the source data. Edit: He used a lot of '' around them.